# Javascript slicing with 3 parameters

Tags: javascript, string, slice, indexof

I am attempting to slice my text, in such a way that if the character lenght of a text exceeds the given value, the text should slice from 0 to the value + also go until the next dot is found, so that we avoid slicing a text midsentence.

I've attempted the following

```
function shorten(text, num)
{
var fulltext=text.toString();
var firstdot = fulltext.indexOf("."); 
if (fulltext.length < num)
{
    return fulltext;
}
else
{
    return fulltext.slice(0, (num + fulltext.indexOf(".")));
}


}
```

So the logic is, if the text is below the given value, full text is returned, if not i want to slice the text, but also include the text, until next dot.
So once the num value has been reached in characters, it should keep searching until it finds the next dot, and then stop.

Example of what i want given lets say 10 as the num value.
"Hello. This is a test example. This part should be removed."

Should return: "Hello. This is a test example." but instead it will return "Hello. This"

Comment: can you show some more examples covering all situations of what you are trying to doing ?

Comment: The 2nd argument to the 2nd call to indexOf should be 10.  `fulltext.indexOf(".", 10)` because that'll tell it where to start its search for the `.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var str = "Hello. This is a test example. This part should be removed."
function shorten(text,num){
    let dot = text.indexOf(".",num),
        end = dot>=0?dot+1:num
    return text.slice(0,end)
}
console.log(shorten(str,6))
```

some definition

lets say limit num is = 10

`indexOf(".",num)` since i am taking 10 letters without caring about dot so i have started checking for `.` after 10 letters that is what second parameter is doing here

`dot>=0?dot+1:num` this is a short hand which checking if `dot` is greater than or equals to 0 if its true then return value of dot otherwise return `num` value

**(dot+1)** `+1` is used to take last dot when slicing without this result will have no dot at end

Comment: Hi Amir. This seems to work like intended. Can you go over the code? How does the IndexOf(".", num) work?
Furthermore, what about the return slicing, how does it actually work?

Comment: @Frederik Lund see i have updated the answer with some definition at bottom if it explains everything if there is still confusion ask freely

Comment: Wow. This is super smart. Very useful to learn! I marked your comment as the solution

Comment: thank for the complement its great to know that my solution is helpfull

Answer (score 1):

Please change some code like this

```js
function shorten(text, num)
{
    const fulltext=text.toString();
    const firstdot = fulltext.indexOf(".", num);
    return fulltext.length < num ? fulltext : fulltext.slice(0, firstdot + 1);
}

console.log(shorten("Hello. This is a test example. This part should be removed.", 10));
```